# VisualStudio PyLint "The filename or extension is too long"

Tags: visual-studio, pylint

Running PyLint or MyPy from VisualStudio gives me: "The filename or extension is too long".
Manually running the executable works well.

Answer (score 0):

After restarting VS PyLint started to work. Not sure why.